# Stateless EJB requiring pre-configuration from another EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have 2 Stateless EJBs as below.

```
@Stateless
public class BeanA {
    @EJB
    private BeanB beanB;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       // trying to do some pre-configuration
       beanB.configure(Map params);
    }
    public void doSomething(){
       beanB.doSomething();
    }         

} 

@Stateless
public class BeanB {

}
```

I need to run some pre-configuration for each instance of BeanB before using it. In most cases the code above does the job, I guess due to the fact that instances of BeanB created only by requests from BeanA instances.

But finally I see that sometimes pool of "BeanB" beans can contain instances that haven't been pre-configured. Following the spec, such behaviour is  normal, so I realized that such an approach was a misuse.

So my question is, is there a legal method to do such a pre-configuration?
Should I create BeanB Stateful instead?

Comment: What specifically are you doing in the pre-configuration of BeanB? Where do the params come from?  It seems as though BeanA and BeanB are tightly coupled, e.g. share some lifecycle together.  Are they ever used independently?

Comment: Parameters are mostly injected into BeanA as env. entries, but these can not be injected into BeanB directly. Parameters are used to determine which particular implementation of the component must be instantiated inside BeanB. Not very expensive to instantiate per request, but still I'd prefer to try doing it just once.

Comment: And you are right, BeanA and BeanB are never used independently.

Comment: Is it possible for BeanB to be managed as a POJO instead of an EJB?  This way you can just instantiate BeanB in the init() method.  You could even consider redesigning BeanB as an inner class of BeanA so that it can call proxied methods on BeanA if necessary.  Unfortunately, its hard to really understand what you're doing without a specific context.

Comment: The `@PostConstruct` method will be invoked only once : Since stateless session beans are never passivated, its lifecycle has only two states, "nonexistent" and "ready". The EJB container creates (and maintains) a pool of instances of a stateless session bean. Dependency injections are performed, if any and then a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`, if one exists, will be invoked. That method will never be invoked then onwards (Also depending upon the container, the `@PostConstruct` method may be transactional unnecessarily. It is unspecified in EJB 3.2 for stateless session beans).

Comment: Unfortunately using a POJO is not an option in this case. Have I got it right, making BeanB stateful guarantees that BeanA instance will work with only one instance of BeanB (so it will be definitely pre-configured)?

Comment: For sure, I'm not talking about calling @PostConstruct twice, just updated the question with a main method to be clear.

Comment: Not exactly.  @Stateful beans are normally scoped to a session. This means that each session will reuse its own BeanB, but not the same one.  You might be more interested in @ Singleton instead which provides a global state.

Answer (score 0):

You never know which instance of stateless bean will be invoked. So it can happen that you configure one instance of BeanB and next time when you use it, you will get another instance which was not configured.
So in this case I recomend use some sessionScopedBean, in this sessionScopedBean you save your parameters from BeanA and everytime when you will use BeanB, you will load these parameters from sessionScopedBean.

You should not have global parameters in BeanB (statelessBean).

What are scopes?
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html